# Why does ${\lambda _{\max }}(A) = \max \{ \frac{1}{{{x^*}x}}:{x^*}Ax = 1\} $?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A \in {M_n}$ be hermitian and suppose that at least one eigenvalue of $A$ is positive ($\lambda $ is eigenvalue of $A$). Why does ${\lambda _{\max }}(A) = \max \{ \frac{1}{{{x^*}x}}:{x^*}Ax = 1\} $?

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ has at least one positive eigenvalue, then the maximal eigenvalue $\lambda_\max(A)$ is positive and can be characterized as
$$\tag{1}
\lambda_\max(A)=\max\left\{\frac{x^*Ax}{x^*x}:x\neq 0\right\}
$$
(I suppose you know that this holds; see the Courant-Fischer theorem.)
Note that $x^*Ax$ is real for any complex vector $x$.
Since $\lambda_\max(A)>0$, we may consider in (1) only $x$ for which $x^*Ax>0$:
$$\tag{2}
\lambda_\max(A)=\max\left\{\frac{x^*Ax}{x^*x}:x\neq 0,\;x^*Ax>0\right\}.
$$
Any Rayleigh quotient $x^*Ax/x^*x$ in (2) can be expressed as
$$
\frac{x^*Ax}{x^*x}=\frac{\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^*Ax}}\right)^*A\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^*Ax}}\right)}{\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^*Ax}}\right)^*\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^*Ax}}\right)}=\frac{1}{y^*y}, \quad y:=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^*Ax}}.
$$
So
$$
\lambda_\max(A)=\max\left\{\frac{1}{y^*y}:y^*Ay=1\right\}
$$